# Print list of tables with option sets

Tags: sql-server, cursor, temp-tables

I would like to print a list of 200 reference table names (refTableA, refTableB, etc) along with the option sets for each table (refTableAID, Description, Code, SortOrder). Some option sets are a single record; others may include over 30 records. 
The script below inserts the Description, Code and SortOrder data into a temp table. I am stumped on how to insert the name of the table (refTableA) into the RefTableName field and the ID (RefTableAID) into the RefTableNameId field. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp
DECLARE @table nvarchar(150) 
DECLARE @sqlinsert nvarchar(max)
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM  Information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME like 'ref%'

Create table #Temp
(
RefTableName nvarchar(150),
RefTableNameId int,
Description nvarchar(100),
Code nvarchar(50),
SortOrder Decimal(5,2)
)

OPEN C1
FETCH next FROM C1 INTO @table
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
BEGIN
  set @sqlinsert='Insert into #Temp (Description, Code, SortOrder) 
    Select Description,Code,SortOrder from *tbl*'       
  set @sqlinsert = REPLACE(@sqlinsert,'*tbl*',@table)
  Print (@sqlinsert)
  Exec (@sqlinsert)   
FETCH next FROM C1 INTO @table
END
CLOSE C1
DEALLOCATE C1
SELECT * from #Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe something you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME =       FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN (
SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2 ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME =      i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
) PT ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
WHERE (PK.TABLE_SCHEMA= '<SCHEMA>' AND PK.TABLE_NAME = '<PK_Table>')
AND (FK.TABLE_SCHEMA= '<SCHEMA>' AND FK.TABLE_NAME = '<FK_TABLE>');
```

Comment: I worked with this answer but it does not help. Back to square one.